# Testing WCF web services using console application returns errors (application/xop+xml” does not match expected type "text/html; charset=UTF-8")

Tags: c#

I create a console application to test a WCF web services. To test my service, I add a Reference service with the URL of my WSDL(https://myservices.fr/Connectors/TokenConnector/ServiceToken.svc?wsdl).

I put in the main method the code to get a new token but I had an error :

> application/xop+xml” does not match expected type "text/html; charset=UTF-8", iscontenttypesupported method is implemented properly.

have you any ideas to fix that please?

```
    ChannelFactory<IServiceTokenChannel> factory = new ChannelFactory<IServiceTokenChannel>("BasicHttpBinding_IServiceToken");
    factory.Open();
    IServiceTokenChannel wcfClientChannel = factory.CreateChannel();
    // Making calls.
    Console.WriteLine("Le service return: " + 
wcfClientChannel.getToken("myLogin", "mypassword", "myEmail")); //Error occurs here.
```

Comment: You might need to update your reference if something has changed

Comment: BTW, the whole `Add Service Reference` flow is a bad practice that leads to alot of headaches. Check out _[WCF the Manual Way… the Right Way](https://www.codemag.com/Article/0809101/WCF-the-Manual-Way%E2%80%A6-the-Right-Way)_.  Case in point - **the above error**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 days of struggling, finally I found a solution of my problem. The error occurs because I didn't define a certificate for my call request. Indeed, to program Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) security, X.509 digital certificates are commonly used to authenticate clients and servers, encrypt, and digitally sign messages (more details here : [Working with Certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/working-with-certificates)).
So to sum up, if you want to test a WCF web services based on https protocol using a console application you can follow the steps below :

1. Create a console application in Visual studio.
2. Add a new reference(System.ServiceModel)
3. Add a new reference service (define the URL of
   your web service ex :
   https://myservices.fr/Connectors/TokenConnector/ServiceToken.svc)
4. In programm class paste the following code after adjusting it to your case :

   ```
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           //instantiate the class ServiceTokenClient wish provide the getToken method with endpoint configuration name and remote adress. 
           //look at web.config or app.config to get the name of endpoint configuration <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceToken" />
           //https://myservices.fr/Connectors/TokenConnector/ServiceToken.svc  is the URL of our web services provided by the host.

           ServiceTokenClient _srvToken = new ServiceTokenClient("BasicHttpBinding_IServiceToken", "https://myservices.fr/Connectors/TokenConnector/ServiceToken.svc");

           //Set a certificate
           // Use the X509Store class to get a handle to the local certificate stores. "My" is the "Personal" store. Don't forget using System.Security.Cryptography and System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
           _srvToken.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
           ((BasicHttpBinding)_srvToken.Endpoint.Binding).Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport; //set the security mode
           ((BasicHttpBinding)_srvToken.Endpoint.Binding).Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate; //set the type of client credential.

           //Making Call
           var _objToken = _srvToken.getToken("myLogin", "mypassword", "myEmail");
           Console.WriteLine("{0}", _objToken.Token);  // Display the token
           Console.ReadKey();

       }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

try to use mtomMessageEncoding in your config file

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding messageEncoding="Mtom">          
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I already tried the messageEncoding="Mtom" but I still have the same error message. I tried many solutions but no way; the web service works fine in soap ui and postman (I can test all services without problems) but not in code.